# How to deny http get requests in IIS running on Windows 2012 R2?

Tags: iis, tfs

We have requests being made against our TFS Server from various git clients.  The requests cause the following unhandled exception logged in the Event Viewer:

```
Detailed Message: TF30065: An unhandled exception occurred.
```

[image]

I selected the Team Foundation Server site in IIS tried the following:

1. Under Request Filtering --> Rules I added a deny string as follows: http://tfs:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/_git/ABC%20MainApp%20Post%20Load%20Automation/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
2. Under Request Filtering -->URL I added the following Deny Sequence: http://tfs:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/_git/ABC%20MainApp%20Post%20Load%20Automation/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack

The Event Viewer is still logging this error every 15 minutes.  How do I block this Get Request in IIS?

Comment: Check the examples, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/configure-request-filtering-in-iis#url-filtering You must not put a full URL in the rule.

Comment: @Lexi Li I did.  I followed the section titled "To configure URL filtering by using the UI".  My deny sequence is:

http://tfs:8080/tfs/defaultcollection/_git/ABC%20MainApp%20Post%20Load%20Automation/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack

What is wrong with my deny sequence?

Comment: You should only put part of the URL, not the whole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the **Deny URL Sequences** tab to create a list of URL sequences for which the request-filtering module will deny access. For example, you can specify `admin/config.xml` as a URL sequence, which denies requests to `http://contoso.com/application/admin/config.xml`. You don't need to type the whole URL, check the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/hh831518(v=ws.11)#url-tab